# How to deal with multiple exceptions thrown in .close()?

Tags: java, exception, java-7

This is Java 7. I have a class which maintains a list of FTP clients (I call them agents) in a class which implements `Closeable`.

On .close() I disconnect them, but of course each of them can throw an exception. Right now the code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void close()
    throws IOException
{
    IOException toThrow = null;

    final List<FtpAgent> list = new ArrayList<>();
    agents.drainTo(list); // <-- agents is a BlockingQueue
    for (final FtpAgent agent: list)
        try {
            agent.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (toThrow == null)
                toThrow = e;
        }

    if (toThrow != null)
        throw toThrow;
}
```

Apart from the lack of logging of each individual exception, is this the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: An alternative would be to throw a new exception that has a list of all exceptions thrown.  The question is what do you want to do with the information?  Should your code act any differently if all agents failed to disconnect, or only some did?

Comment: @SimonC no reason to act differently; neither do I expect users to do anything specific with regards to this exception. I was just wondering whether there were some better way to deal with such a situation. Also, "a new exception that has a list of all exceptions thrown" <-- you mean as a constructor parameter to a custom exception?

Comment: In which case I would just log the exceptions and return.

Comment: @SimonC yes, that is also a solution I guess... (I didn't even think about it this way)